# Pre-populating a form field with HTML

Tags: forms, field, auto-populate

I would like to pre-populate this form:
https://npo1.networkforgood.org/Donate/Donate.aspx?npoSubscriptionId=1006493

Specifically one field.

```
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$body$formControl$stateControl$question_1241326" type="text" maxlength="100" id="ctl00_ctl00_body_formControl_stateControl_question_1241326" style="width:150px;">
```

(That's the "specific fund" box all the way at the bottom.)

I want that field to be populated with the name of my charity, but I can't figure out how to make a link that will populate that field with the name when the link is clicked, or if that's even possible.

I don't have access to the scripting of the target site, but I do have access to my site (where the link will be), it's a Wordpress site, if there is a Javascript, PHP, or other solution.

Thanks.

Comment: can you use jQuery? Also for clarification you want to add a name to an input on your website or someone elses?

Comment: I want to add the name to a form on someone else's site. The link will be on my site.

Comment: I do not believe that this is possible with just the use of a link. There are things that allow you to do this but you need control of the browser to do it. Which I do not believe you can make happen with just a link. You could if the server had the logic to parse the url and fill in the form but you will need more than you can get for this to work for anyone that visits the link.